# Second stack navigator nested inside the first modal stack navigator not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a parent navigator that sets a modal as follows -:

```
function Launcher({navigation}){
  return(
    <Launch.Navigator
      mode="modal"
    >
      <Launch.Screen
        name='launchButton'
        component={LaunchButton}
      />
      <Launch.Screen
        name='multiform'
        component={MultiForm}
        options={{
          headerShown:false
        }}
      />
    </Launch.Navigator>
  )
}
```

Multiform is a second navigator nested inside the first as follows  -:

```
function MultiForm({navigation}) {
  return(<FormNavigator.Navigator
      initialRouteName='formOne'
    >
    <FormNavigator.Screen
      name="formOne"
      component={FormOne}
    />
    <FormNavigator.Screen
      name="formTwo"
      component={FormTwo}
    />
    </FormNavigator.Navigator>
  )
}
```

I know the nesting works because the following component from inside LaunchButton works -:

```
<Button title="Go to form two" onPress={
      ()=>navigation.navigate('multiform', {
      screen:'formTwo'
      })}
    />
```

But the following components from FormOne do not work

```
  <Button title="go to form two" onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('formTwo')}/>

  <Button title="nested" onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('multiform', {
          screen:'formTwo'
        })}/>
```

But the first button is supposed to work, is it not?

Thank you for your help!

**Edit**
FormOne is a modal. I didn't think that was the issue because `navigate.goBack` works -- which should mean that the modal does have access to navigation actions?

Comment: Please add more description and detail about the issue.

Comment: This is mostly it. But an additional detail that might be actually useful -- form one is a fullscreen modal and when I replace it with a View component, the navigation works fine. But I need it to be a modal.